# jQuery multi-draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

**Edit#1:**

Since I asked this problem, I made a script which allows the elements to move together, but with problems. :(

```
$(this).append(

    $('<div class="elem '+classes+'" style="width: 210px; height: 30px" data-modby="'+ui.draggable.attr("data-for")+'"><p>'+text+'</p></div>')
    .resizable({
        grid: 10,
        maxHeight: 120,
        maxWidth: 600,
        minHeight: 30,
        minWidth: 210,
        containment: ".box-section"
    })
    .draggable({
        grid: [10,10],
        containment: ".box-section",
        scroll: false,
        helper: "original",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            posTopArray = [];
            posLeftArray = [];
                if ($(this).hasClass("r-active")) {
                    $(".elem.r-active").each(function(i) {
                        thiscsstop = $(this).css('top');
                        if (thiscsstop == 'auto') thiscsstop = 0;
                        thiscssleft = $(this).css('left');
                        if (thiscssleft == 'auto') thiscssleft = 0;
                        posTopArray[i] = parseInt(thiscsstop);
                        posLeftArray[i] = parseInt(thiscssleft);
                    });
                }

                begintop = $(this).offset().top;
                beginleft = $(this).offset().left;
         },
         drag: function(event, ui) {
            var topdiff = $(this).offset().top - begintop;
            var leftdiff = $(this).offset().left - beginleft;
            if ($(this).hasClass("r-active")) {
                $(".elem.r-active").each(function(i) {
                    $(this).css('top', posTopArray[i] + topdiff);
                    $(this).css('left', posLeftArray[i] + leftdiff);
                });
            }
        }
    })
);
```

The actual problem is the moved elements have to stay in the containment box (called `.box-section` and if I have a single element it works fine. Also if i have two elements has not the same width, if i pick the sorter one and drag, I can pull out the longer of the container.

Also, if I move them fast (like a ninja) they will slip, and they won't be in the same grid they used to be.

---

**30 percent solved since:**

I'm going to make a new thingy which can drag and drop items to a box, and resize them.

My problem is that, I can't make them move together. But with some rules.

Rule one: They must move based on a 10x10px grid.
Rule two: They can't move outside their frame.
(Resize is an issue which i simply can't imagine, so I don't care about it, resize will be later)

I made a fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9fueY/ you can see this.

In the right side, you can see inputs and a and a checkbox (and on hover a button).
The checkbox is the draggable object, drag it to the image. Now you have some text or a star appeared on the left.
If you type anything to the inputs, it refreshes the text.

OnHover the right boxes you can see a button. By clicking on it, will make a clone of the first element. Drag it inside.

If you click to a right-side box, it will glow blue. Click to two boxes on the right, makes all the two textfields glow blue in the image.

Now this is the case when i want them to move together. :D

What's your opinion, what should I do with this?

Thank you very much. - Répás

Comment: This will be bounty again -.-

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin i developed for dragging elements together. Please do use it if it makes sense.

https://github.com/someshwara/MultiDraggable